# Alter /proc/cmdline for QEMU emulated process

Tags: qemu

I am using `qemu-arm` to run a statically linked binary on an Ubuntu system. There is little to no chance of emulating the entire system.

The binary reads `/proc/cmdline` as it starts up, to check for a specific parameter concerning MTD partitions. Obviously, my `/proc/cmdline` does not match.

Is there any easy way to alter the contents of `/proc/cmdline` for this emulated binary?

Answer (score 1):

The typical way to do something like this is to write a small library that intercepts open/read and fakes out the data your program is looking for, and then arrange for that library to be loaded by passing in an `LD_PRELOAD` environment variable (QEMU's `-E` option).

It's pretty straightforward; you could adapt the instructions here on [emulating NVRAM in QEMU](http://www.devttys0.com/2012/03/emulating-nvram-in-qemu/).